# SFTP through multiple computers

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp

I want to copy a file from A to D. The computer can only access the ones right next to it.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Computer A <-> Computer B <-> Computer C <-> Computer D |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Right now, i copy it from A to B with SFTP, then ssh into B, copy it to C, ssh into C and so on. When done, i go back and close every ssh session and delete the files.

Is there an easy way to send the file from A to D in a more efficient way? Right now, the file has to be completly downloaded to every computer in the row, just to be deleted afterwards. No, using Floppy disks and walking is not more efficient.

Comment: Look at ssh `ProxyCommand` directive you can configure it to connect to D and it will understand it needs to first connect to B then to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LocalPortForwarding to set a local port listening and served as destination SSH service.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Computer A <-> Computer B <-> Computer C <-> Computer D |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

On [ComputerC], create a listener on socket localhost:2022 served as ComputerD's SSH by forwarding traffic to ComputerD:22

```
$ ssh -L2022:ComputerD:22 ComputerD
```

On [ComputerB], create a listener on socket localhost:2022 served as ComputerD's SSH by forwarding traffic to localhost:2022 of ComputerC

```
$ ssh -L2022:localhost:2022 ComputerC
```

On [ComputerA], create a listener on socket localhost:2022 served as ComputerD's SSH by forwarding traffic to localhost:2022 of ComputerB

```
$ ssh -L2022:localhost:2022 ComputerB
```

Using port 2022 on ComputerA as ComputerD's SSH service, to copy the file

```
$ scp -P2022 file localhost:/path/
```